# Is it possible to have a windows service call a VBScript that removes the service and installs a new version?

Tags: .net, vbscript, windows-services

I have a VBScript that, when called manually or from code being debugged, successfully removes and reinstalls a service. So the script works.

The problem is that when calling the same script from within the service that needs to be removed, the script runs but the service is not removed.

I have made the script write to a log for a few minutes and while is executing I manually remove the service and the script keeps writing to the log until time expires so is not like the service is in control.

I have attempted to use the `Process` class to call `cmd.exe` and call the `cscript.exe` with the path to my script and I have also tried the same but using `Shell()`.

So my question is. Is it even possible to have a service call a script that updates the service to a newer version? I will mention again that when the script is called from stemware else it works.

This is how I call my scripts from withing the service.
Calling the same code from the debugger works.

```
Private Sub CallScript(pathToScript As String)
    Dim start As New ProcessStartInfo
    start.FileName = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe"
    start.Arguments = pathToScript
    start.UseShellExecute = False
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    start.RedirectStandardError = True
    Dim myproc As New Process
    myproc.StartInfo = start
    myproc.Start()
End Sub
```

Or

```
Private Sub CallScript(pathToScript As String)     
    Shell(String.Format("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cscript.exe {0}", pathToScript))   
End Sub
```

This is that part of the script that fails when Call script is called from withing the service:

```
public sub UnistallService()
    Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    oShell.run "cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\MySoftware\Services\WorkflowServices\AutoUpdate\AutoUpdateService.exe"" -u", 0 ,True
    WScript.sleep 10000
end sub
```

When called from visual studio or if I call the script from a console it works.

This is code inside the service .exe that performs the installation:

```
      Protected Sub InstallService()
        Using installer As AssemblyInstaller = GetInstaller()
            Dim state As IDictionary = New Hashtable()
            Try
                Me.WriteToLog(String.Format("Installing {0}", Me.ServiceName))
                installer.Install(state)
                installer.Commit(state)
               If Me.IsInstalled() then
                  Me.WriteToLog("Installation complete")
               End iF             
            Catch ex As Exception
                Try
                    installer.Rollback(state)
                Catch
                End Try
                Me.WriteToLog(String.Format("{0}", ex.Message), ex)
                Throw
            End Try
        End Using
```

End Sub

```
 Protected Sub UninstallService()
    If Not Me.IsInstalled() Then
        Return
    End If

    If Me.IsRunning() Then
        Me.StopService()
    End If
    Try
        Using installer As AssemblyInstaller = GetInstaller()
            Dim state As IDictionary = New Hashtable()
            Try
                Me.WriteToLog(String.Format("Removing Service {0}", Me.ServiceName))
                installer.Uninstall(state)
                If Me.IsInstalled Then
                    Throw New Exception(String.Format("Unable to remove Service: {0}", Me.ServiceName))
                Else
                    Me.WriteToLog(String.Format("Service Removed"))
                End If
            Catch
                Throw
            End Try
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.WriteToLog(String.Format("{0}", ex.Message), ex)
        Throw
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is what the service main looks like:

```
Shared Sub Main(args As String())
   Dim svc As New AutoUpdateService()

    If Environment.UserInteractive Then
        If args.Length = 1 Then
            Select Case args(0)
                Case "-install", "-i"
                    svc.InstallService()
                    Exit Select
                Case "-uninstall", "-u"
                    svc.UninstallService()
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
            End Select
        End If
    Else
        Dim ServicesToRun As ServiceBase()
        ServicesToRun = New ServiceBase() {New AutoUpdateService()}
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: You say the script is started, so the code you posted apparently works. What are the contents of your VBScript?

Comment: A bunch of file management stuff and the installation of the service. To execute that code the script calls cmd and the executable for the service installer\uninstaller. I design it to take 2 parameters -i and -u depending on what I want to do. On normal command line it works like a charm. But when the service calls the script it fails. If I call the vbs script directly it stops and uninstalls the service, creates a back up of the old installation, cleans the folder, adds all the new dll's and starts the new service. But when the service is the caller it fails to uninstall.

Comment: Please do not paraphrase.

Comment: Updated the code to show the details of how it works